# write all the curl arguments in a separate file to execute multipart/form-data request on webservices

Tags: http, curl, http-post, sh, multipartform-data

I need to write all the curl arguments in a separate file(myconfig.txt) to be executed and output for each different lines of command in output.txt, output1.txt, output2.txt...so on.
The webservices should be requested with post (multipart/form-data) method. 
I am trying this command `curl -K myconfig.txt -o output.txt`
contents of

> myconfig.txt include `URL="http://1x2.2x1.x6.1x2:3000/latto/get_notifications"<option="to";mobile="+91999xx6xx3x">` into the output.txt - 'Cannot get /latto/get_notifications'. It seems like web-services are being requested as get method. Please anyone tell me the syntax to write in myconfig file. So that I can get the right output in file.

---

However, When I run this command `sudo curl --form option="to" --form mobile="+9199999yyyxx" 1x2.2x1.x6.1x2:3000/latto/get_notifications`, output is successfully printed in terminal.

Comment: It would help if you post the complete content of myconfig.txt. (**Replace password and such.**) Curl has some different --data options: Maybe `--data-ascii <data>` might help you. Take a look at the man page.

Comment: `URL="http://1x2.2x1.x6.1x2:3000/latto/get_notifications"<option="to";mobile="+91999xx6xx3x"> -o output.txt` this is in a line into the myconfig.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This webservice accepts request in POST method and enctype multipart/form-data

```
    URL="http://my.test.domain/get_notifications"
    -F option=to
    -F mobile=+91999xx6xx3x
```

After a lot of hit and trial, I got this working: `curl -k config.txt` with config.txt containing the above.

Answer (score 1):

When I do a `curl -k config.txt` with config.txt containing this:

```
URL="http://my.test.domain/index.php"
-d option="to"
-d mobile="+91999xx6xx3x"
```

I get the result:

```
POST
array(2) {
  ["option"]=>
  string(4) ""to""
  ["mobile"]=>
  string(15) "" 91999xx6xx3x""
}
```

So I don't known what you mean with `<option ...>` but when you put it into your config file as stated above, it should work.

Btw. here is the php script that answered:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."\n";
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the attempt. However, This is not the answer as I have clearly written in my question that : Request is sent as a `POST` method via `multipart/form-data`.